# Why is the functor from the lattice of open subsets of the reals to Set contravariant?

Tags: category-theory, functors

> …our sheaf of continuous functions on the reals consists in specifying, for each open subset $U ⊆ R$, the set $C(U,R)$ of real continuous functions on $U$. Clearly, when $V ⊆ U$ is a smaller open subset, every $f ∈ C(U,R)$ restricts as some $f|V ∈ C(V,R)$. Writing $O(R)$ for the lattice of open subsets of the reals, we get so a contravariant functor $C(−,R): O(R) \rightarrow Set$.

https://tcsc.lakecomoschool.org/files/2018/06/Como2018.pdf

Assuming $O(R)$ is a category where there is an arrow $f: A \rightarrow B$ if $A \subseteq B$, why does this imply a contravariant functor to $Set$?

In $Set$, the arrows are functions between sets.

Does this functor map an arrow in $O(R)$ to a function $g: B \rightarrow A$?

Or the reverse, $f: A \rightarrow B$ if $B \subseteq A$, and $g: B \rightarrow A$ is the inclusion map of $B$ into $A$?

Comment: It seems very similar to dual spaces in Linear Algebra -  given a morphism $T:V \to W$, the corresponding dual map $T^*:W^* \to V^*$ takes $f:\left( w \mapsto f(w)\right) \mapsto f \circ T:\left(v \mapsto f(Tv)\right)$

Answer (score 1):

If $U\subseteq V$ and $f:V\to\mathbb{R}$ then the construction turns it into $f_{|U}:U\to\mathbb{R}$. And therefore an arrow $U\to V$ is transformed into the arrow $$C(V,\mathbb{R})\to C(U,\mathbb{R})$$
$$f\mapsto f_{|U}$$ so contravariant.